Integrate Blazor-Component in Razor-Page (*.cshtml) - Events
i want to implement a Blator-Component within a EventCallBack in a razor-Page (*.cshtml). Currently the component is shown and i can click the buttons inside the component with the correct reaction of the component.
Now i want to get the events of the component and call some functions in the razor-file. But this does not work.
My Blazor-Component has a EventCallBack like this:
[Parameter]
public EventCallback<bool> OnValidate { get; set; }

and is triggert like this:
OnValidate.InvokeAsync( false );

My razor-page implement the component like this:
<component type="typeof(MyBlazorComponent)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered"
           param-Width=200
           param-Height=50
           param-OnValidate="@(EventCallback.Factory.Create<bool>(this, HandleAction))" />

and the called function is
void HandleAction( bool actionResult )
{
    t = actionResult;
}

I hoped that the function HandleAction is called when the EventCallBack is invoked but it does not.
